# how to implement "which " command in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm struggling to get the functionality of the "which command" that appears in LINUX, which I require to do the same in C.

I explain my question. In Linux Terminal, if I enter "which file1.txt", it searches in the entire filesystem and prints the path. The syntax for the same is "which ".

Similarly, I want to do the same functionality using the C program. I should only use C. Could anybody help me with how to complete this? I tried many ways, but unable to complete it.

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#undef _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

void traverse(char *fn, int indent) {
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *entry;
  int count;
  char path[1025];
  struct stat info;

  for (count=0; count<indent; count++) printf("  ");
  printf("%s\n", fn);

  if ((dir = opendir(fn)) == NULL)
    perror("opendir() error");
  else {
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      if (entry->d_name[0] != '.') {
          
        strcpy(path, fn);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, entry->d_name);
        if (stat(path, &info) != 0)
          fprintf(stderr, "stat() error on %s: %s\n", path,
                  strerror(errno));
        else if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
               traverse(path, indent+1);
      }
    }
    
    closedir(dir);
  }
}

main() {
  puts("Directory structure:");
  traverse("/", 0);
}
```

Comment: Note: if you want a C solution, you should avoid the [C++] tag. OK, just removed by @HongOoi

Comment: So what happened when you tried this program?

Comment: If you're trying to replicate the behaviour of the `which` command line utility, then this isn't right. It's supposed to search for executable programs in the user's path, which you can find in the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to search for the filename provided to your program, you should at least take a look at your command line arguments. Implicit int type for functions is ancient feature and should be avoided in 21st century. Also empty parameter list is deprecated. Look up the valid signatures for `main` and pick the one that allows you taking a filename as argument.

Comment: Please add your input and output as well as expected output to your question.

Comment: You probably want to look at `nftw` to do the file tree walk.

Comment: linux being open source, you could have a look at the "real" which command implementation.